# Sequelize count from subquery

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a complex query A with joins, groupBy, etc.
I just want to count the number of results of A.

Basically I would like to do this : `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (A)`

=> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ...)`

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for an hour, but to no avail. It's unbelievable that this information is so hard to find for an ORM that claims to be complete!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: this query seems a little odd.  If you want to count all records, you don't need groupby.  (do you need a distinct count?)  Could you explain what you are trying to count? or show the entire SQL (if there are ~< 5 joins).

Comment: The groupBy clause is part of the original query (A), I can't remove it. If I add `COUNT(*)` in the attributes, the groupBy applies (but I don't want a count for each group but a count of all records returned by A).

Comment: Otherwise I had an idea which consists in recovering the SQL generated by sequelize then writing literally `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ({sql})` but there again it does not seem to be easily feasible...

Comment: is the query A is already written in Sequelize or in SQL that you are importing from somewhere? (what do you mean by "I can't remove it".)  Could you clarify in question?

Comment: The request comes from a business method that returns an object of type `sequelize.FindOptions`. The method is used elsewhere and there is no question of copying it to adapt it (in terms of maintenance it will be a pain if you have to think about making changes in several places).


If I had the sql code of the original query it would be simpler as explained above (literally writing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ({sql})`...).


I think the question is rather simple: Does Sequelize allow to count the number of results of a subquery? Apparently not ... :-(

Comment: you are right. afaik Sequelize doesn't support using a subquery for `FROM` query.  That's why I am trying to think the alternative.  If you are getting the `FindOptions` (not the whole select query like A), you can try `YourModel.count(FindOptions)`.

Comment: On the other note, "The method is used elsewhere and there is no question of copying it to adapt it".  => This is the great use case of `scope` https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/scopes/

Comment: Thank you for your answers Emma :-) ! I did not know the concept of `scope`.

Unfortunately `model.count(findOptions)` returns all records with a `count` attribute relative to each group (because of `groupBy`).

The solution I chose for the moment is to get all the records (`raw` and only the id to limit the memory impact) then to count them with `length` but it's not great ...